# How do I align this text in bootstrap? [Responsive]

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to get this text to be aligned next to the image here. (see picture) I am having problems with making it responsive and even just getting it there in the first place.
[image]

```css
aside .box {
  position: relative;
}
aside .card {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateY(-100px);
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <p class="col-md-6 offset-md-6">Project Name</p>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div class="row">
      <aside class="col-4">
        <div class="box">
          <div class="card">
            <img
              class="card-img-top"
              src="https://picsum.photos/600/200"
              alt="Card image cap"
            />
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">
                Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up
                the bulk of the card's content.
              </p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </aside>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: result]

Does this code work for you?

Edited: based upon your request to make it more responsive in smaller devices.

```
<header>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="jumbotron col-12">
                <p class="project__name position-relative col-md-4 col-lg-6 offset-md-4 offset-sm-0">Project Name</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <aside class="col-12 col-md-4">
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="card">
                        <img class="card-img-top" src="https://picsum.photos/600/200" alt="Card image cap" />
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">
                                Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.
                            </p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </aside>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

CSS: changes that I would personally do.

```
@media (min-width:768px) {
    aside .card {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        transform: translateY(-100px);
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
    .project__name {
        top: 3rem;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, it does. But when you make the page smaller it doesn't adjust with it. How would I be able to make the project name responsive?

Comment: well, you are using absolute position which may make it harder to be responsive so, you are going to need to use `media` query to prevent these changes and let the flow back to the way it was in order to make it responsive.

Comment: I edited my answer and made it responsive to smaller devices based on my own perspective feel free to change it however you like.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm going to just add a lot of media-queries to handle all those cases :)